# unable to get property 'd' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am querying my SharePoint 2013 list using a promise but I get an abnormal behavior.  As you will see from my code below, the value of 'promise.responseJSON.d.results.length == 1' condition returns an error but if I comment out the if statement generating and console.log(promise.responseJSON.d.results.length), I get a value of 1.  I don't understand why this is happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var promise = getData();
  promise.done(function(data) {
    return data;
  });

  console.log(typeof(promise));

  //returns an error 'unable to get property 'd' of undefined or null reference
  if (promise.responseJSON.d.results.length === 1) {
    alert("show ED DOM Elements");
  } else {
    alert("Do not show ED DOM Elements");
  }
  console.log(promise.responseJSON.d.results.length); //returns 1 if I comment out the if statement above

});

function getData() {
  //console.log(itemID);
  var itemID = getQueryString("ID");
  var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Document Approval')/items?$filter=(BackToAD eq 'Yes') and  (ID eq " + itemID + ")";
  console.log(endPointUrl);

  var headers = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  };

  return $.ajax({
    url: endPointUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: headers

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

image of returned object from promise showing that 'd' does exist
[image]

Any help and insight would be much appreciated. This has been driving me crazy for a few hours.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  This is totally different.  Please read through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still trying to access the data outside of the `done` handler and as a result you are getting errors. You need to be careful trusting the browser's `console.log` with async requests because they will often show the state a point later than when you called `console.log`. Here's an example using a simplified versions of your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var promise = getData();
  promise.done(function(data) {
    console.log("promise readystate in done", promise.readyState);
    if (promise.responseJSON.userId)
      console.log("data inside done", promise.responseJSON);
  });

  console.log("promise readystate outside of done", promise.readyState);
  // uncommenting the line below will throw an error becuase responseJSON is not defined yet
  // console.log("data outside of done: ", promise.responseJSON.userId)
});

function getData() {
  var endPointUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  var headers = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  };
  return $.ajax({
    url: endPointUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: headers
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that the promise ready state outside of the `done` function is `1` That [means the request hasn't even been sent yet.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) Inside `done` the really state is `4` which means it's complete.

This all means that you need to handle you logic of dealing with the data inside `done()` or call a function from `done()` and pass in the data.

Comment: Thank you for your version and explanation. Very helpful!